# How do I prevent empty complex objects when all properties are null or empty even with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)?

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have the following...

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Address extends ResultSetParser{
    // TODO: Need Escaped
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "addressLine1")
    private String line1;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "addressLine2")
    private String line2;
    ...
}
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Client extends ResultSetParser{
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private Address address;
    ...
}
```

However, when the address is empty I still get...

```
    <client>
        ...
        <address/>
```

Why is this and how can I avoid it?

**Update**

To make clear, this is a db record with multiple properties that are all null if this situation occurs. This means it is not possible, without extensive refactoring, to add logic to check each value in the object (over 100+ columns in the returned procedure). I am looking for some way to tell it to not create the object if all properties are null WITHOUT some massive ugly if statement.

Also in this particular example the Address object was NEVER CREATED (Initialized). However, frameworks like Lombok could have done something.

Answer (score -1):

Annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` takes an effect in case when field `address` is null. Make sure that `address` is not initialized in a way `client.setAddress(new Address());`.

Also make sure that serialization is performed by Jackson (e.g. via `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper`) and not by JAXB marshaller.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question because I asked how I can remove completely empty records. I cannot (without extensive logic) prevent an empty object getting created from an empty DB object.

Comment: I also confirmed in this case I was not initializing anything manually. The mapping only happens if there is a record and in this case I never got an address record. So an instance of the address object is never created manually. I think this means I need to downvote the answer as it does not account for situation where I have never manually instantiated an instance